# How to "create new receiving address" from recently installed full node, (0.21.0) with new encrypted wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, address-generation

On March 11th, 2021, I completed my downloaded of the full node from Bitcoin Core, (Bitcoin-0.21.0-win64-setup), on my Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700 CPU @ 2.90GHz - 16.0GB,  Windows 10Pro.

I created a new wallet with encryption and I named it.

The "get new address" box remains grayed out.

After unlocking with "passphrase" [] 100),

Console command "getnewaddress" was unsuccessful.  "update" says I'm wallet version 169900.

Node is fully synced and has remained in operation, with "check box" saying up to date, and with 10 active connections to Bitcoin network.

I haven't seen any new problems reported, with this issue, since 0.21.0 release.  I'm pretty sure I've tried and was unsuccessful with all other suggestions for the same issue.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.  Further, I'm a boomer noob, who left programming after the mouse was introduced.

Uggh! Wondering if I should delete node and start over without encrypted wallet?

Comment: If the passphrase command is unsuccessful, it means your password isn't correct.

Comment: The pass phrase command was only used to unlock the encryption on wallet. It was successful and showed padlock icon open. Then while open. I instituted the other commands.

Comment: Can you paste the full output of the `getwalletinfo` command?

Comment: 20:31:52
￼
getwalletinfo


20:31:52
￼
{
  "walletname": "trlight",
  "walletversion": 169900,
  "format": "bdb",
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "unconfirmed_balance": 0.00000000,
  "immature_balance": 0.00000000,
  "txcount": 0,
  "keypoololdest": 9223372036854775807,
  "keypoolsize": 0,
  "keypoolsize_hd_internal": 0,
  "unlocked_until": 0,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "private_keys_enabled": true,
  "avoid_reuse": false,
  "scanning": false,
  "descriptors": false
}

Comment: What happens when you use the `keypoolrefill` (while having the wallet unlocked)?

Comment: Just tried. first time no result, so I closed wallet, opened it and still nothing so I tried again but different report resulted.

Comment: 09:25:44
￼
walletpassphrase(…)


09:25:45
￼
null


09:26:12
￼
keypoolrefill


09:26:12
￼
null


09:27:40
￼
Executing command without any wallet


09:27:40
￼
walletpassphrase(…)


09:27:40
￼
null


09:28:13
￼
keypoolrefill


09:28:13
￼
null


09:29:02
￼
getnewaddress


09:29:02
￼
Error: This wallet has no available keys (code -4)

Comment: Note that this question was apparently resolved in this Bitcoin Core issue: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/21456. Please feel free to write an answer from the content linked.